# Write a csv file and send it with other name as attachment in android

Tags: java, android, csv, sendmail, file-rename

Following code is working to save the `Data.csv` file and send it by mail.

I want to save the file as it is with the current name `Data.csv` and then send this file with other name. For Example, `newname.csv`.

Code is sending `newname.csv` but it is getting saved in the device as `Data.csv`. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
/* Making A New File */ 
File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/FolderData"); 
dir.mkdirs(); 
file = new File(dir, "Data.csv"); 
out = new FileOutputStream(file); out.write(combinedString.getBytes()); 

//want to send the file Data.csv that is saved but with other name 
  File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DeltioData");
            File file2 = new File(dir,"newname.csv");
            File Nf=file;
            Nf.renameTo(file2);
                  //

Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(Nf); Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "any subject"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@yahoo.gr"}); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1); 
sendIntent.setType("text/html"); startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: WHere are you setting newname.csv?

Comment: Data.csv and newname.csv is the same file but I want to  save as data.csv and to send as attachment with name newname.csv

Comment: Right, but where are you trying to set newname.csv to the attatchment? There's no line trying to achieve that in your code

Comment: I add code for this but is not working

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have just to

1-copy Data.csv to newname.csv

2-send newname.csv

3-delete file newname.csv
(if sender is activity so, startForResult (start mailer intent with startActivityForResult) and delete file on ActivityResult)